# Should the tag wiki for [security] direct people to Information Security Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, tag-wiki

Would it be ok to edit the tag wiki of the [security] tag (on the main Super User) to ask people to consider asking the question on our sister site the [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/)?  It appears that many of the questions with that tag would be more approperiate on that site.

If there is consensus that this is a good idea, please edit the tag wiki, don't wait for me.  Thanks.

Update: wow, Oliver Salzburg's answer has made me find out that there's more to tag wikis than that short summary that is displayed whenever you hover on the link, and the full tag wiki does already mention Information Security SE.  During my stay on other SE sites, I somehow never noticed this.  But that might mean people asking new questions won't notice the full wiki either!

Let me modify my meta question this way then: should we mention Information Security SE in the short tag description that appears whenever soneone hovers the tag link?

Answer (score 4):

#### Tag Wiki

We're doing the same for [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx), so, why not?

#### Tag Wiki Excerpt

When talking only about the excerpt, then I wouldn't recommend doing this. The excerpt has enough space to explain what [security](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/security) is about. The space shouldn't be sacrificed for giving users directions on where else they might ask their question.

You brought up the point that a user might not even know about the full tag wiki. Likewise, users often don't even know about the excerpt (because they use the tags without reading the excerpt). This is especially common with new users.

From what I can tell, we hardly ever migrate questions from Super User to Security. So there doesn't even really seem to be an issue with people posting their question on the "wrong" site.

Comment: Thank you for the relevant example.  See my update of the question.

Comment: Understood, thank you for the answer.  I'll wait for other opinions before choosing an accepted answer.